# Is the "History" tab gone from Wikipedia after latest update?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, motorola-moto-z2-play, wiki

After latest update to Wikipedia mobile app for Android (3-4 weeks ago, the one that introduced many changes in user interface), I cannot find "History" functionality or tab.

I've checked the usual place (three dot menu on article) and probably all other and... nothing.

Is this functionality removed after the latest update of this  application? How can I browse articles that I've read recently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still there. But you have to click on Search to view your history.

[image: IMG:]

You need to be in the main Wiki app screen for this to work. If you tap "Search" (the same icon, in the same place) while being on any article, you will only be able to see list of recent searches and not list of recently visited articles.